# How to aggregate unnested data fields with nested data fields in same dataset?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, nested-table, unnest

I have a table with some nested fields and some unnested fields.

Example of table: 
Unnested fields:

```
uniqueid     (STRING)
date         (DATETIME)
visits       (INT)
hits         (INT)
```

Nested fields:

```
hits.engagements (INT)
hits.website     (STRING)
```

I need to create one flattened table that includes the following fields:

```
date
website
SUM(visits)
SUM(hits)
SUM(engagements)
```

My problem is that I can't sum the nested field "engagements" without the ruining the numbers for the unnested field "visits".

The unnested visits, and hits fields are being duplicated across all the "unnestings".

I've tried to use the UNNEST() function as seen below, but this is actually what ruins my already unnested values.

So, when i unnest I get the correct results for engagements summed but I get the wrong result for visits when summed.

I also tried using the method of 
WITH OFFSET AS OFFSET

```
SELECT
  date,
  hits.website,
  SUM(visits),
  SUM(hits)
  SUM(hits.engagement)
FROM
  `global-digital.175914969.ga_sessions_20190427`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits
GROUP BY
  1, 2
```

I expect to end up with a table where each row consists of the the correct summed values for each website, for each date.

Comment: you should include some test data, expected output and table definition, it would help :)

Comment: A common workaround in this case is to run two queries in separate WITH() statements, one which totals the unnested values you require and a second that sums the nested values, then join these results together, groups by date.

Comment: does your data look like this? `1, 2019-08-09, 10, 5, [(20, 'site1'), (30, 'site2')]`

Comment: if so, how do you want to split these 5 hits for two websites, 2.5 for each?